# How to populate two dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to populate a 2D array of objects and get a result like this example:

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var data = new[] {
    new object[] { 22, "cust1_fname","cust1_lname",guid },
    new object[] { 23, "cust2_fname","cust2_lname",guid },
    new object[] { 24, "cust3_fname","cust3_lname",guid },
};
```

[image]

I tried this way:

[image]

But the objects are not added as direct children under the 2D array as in the first example

Comment: Have you tried `my2dArr[i] = datalist[i]`?